# Problem with ComboBox dropdown width after changing window size in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm working on an Java app that changes components size after it's window size changes and i have a problem with ComboBox dropdown. After window size changes, first expanding of the dropdown doesnt change it's width and i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRyUb.png). When i expand the list second time, it works well, but only when i use following code:

```
        comboBoxWindowSize.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<WindowSize>, ListCell<WindowSize>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<WindowSize> call(ListView<WindowSize> param) {
                ListCell cell = new ListCell<WindowSize>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(WindowSize windowSize, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(windowSize, empty);
                        setPrefHeight(padH25);
                        getListView().setPrefWidth(padW150);
                        if (!empty) {
                            setText(windowSize.toString());
                        } else {
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```

When i don't use this code, width stays incorrect all the time. I want dropdown width to be equal to ComboBox width. Will you help me fix that?

Comment: Do you have any prefWidth or minWidth / maxWidth set on the comboBox? Try to remove all the width indications and let Java do the required sizing.
It will also depends on the parent of the combobox.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change anything. The only indication to combobox width is comboBoxWIndowSize.setPrefWidth(padW150);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found an answer. It's very ugly, but it actually works.
Just like i said above, it's size is incorrect only in the first expanding. So all i had to do, is to expand and collapse it programmatically after i change window size:

```
            comboBoxWindowSize.show();
            comboBoxWindowSize.hide();
```

And thats all.